# Questions about user authentication strategies

Tags: authentication, user-management, single-sign-on

I am currently re-doing the IT infrastructure at my company. It's currently all over the place, so I'm trying to re-organise everything from the ground up. First thing I thought I would tackle is central user management and authentication, and good password security and management.

We have under 10 employees, most using Mac's but a few Windows PC's. We have a SAN that we use as a central file share. Currently each user just has a password that they log in to their compute with, and a username and password to log on to the file share. Additionally, our password security and management could do with an upgrade as we don't currently use a password manager or any other similar system.

After doing lots of research, I was planning on rolling out the following:

- Set up OpenLDAP on our on-site server to handle user management and authentication.
- Set up staff computers to authenticate using LDAP. It looks like this is built-in to OSX, and I should use http://pgina.org/ for Windows.
- Set up LastPass for all staff, only allow logging in via SSO and pass authentication back to our on-site server.

This way, we get a password manager for websites so we can enforce good password management and security, strong authentication measures to access the password manager, and manage user accounts and access to all logins and passwords from a central location.

First, does this sound like a good plan? Are there any other options to consider?

Second, I'm a bit stuck on connecting third party web apps to OpenLDAP. I know that most providers (including LastPass) use SAML for SSO/federated access, but I don't know how to set that up. Does OpenLDAP support SAML authentication? What if I want to enable MFA (possibly including mobile authenticators and/or Yubikeys)?

I'm guessing that I might need another piece of software in front of OpenLDAP to handle SAML/MFA/Yubikey/etc, and then just have that look up the user details from OpenLDAP but I don't know what I'm searching for and haven't found anything.

Edit: Of course my search found something immediately after posting this! Should I be using CAS (https://apereo.github.io/cas) for web based SAML authentication? It looks like this will allow me to handle web based logins and authenticate them via the LDAP directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoult take a look at the [Univention Corporate Server](https://www.univention.de/). This is a linux based distribution providing LDAP, Active Directory (via Samba 4), SAML and many other third party applications. Using [privacyIDEA](https://privacyidea.org) on the Univention Corporate Server you can also setup 2FA in your network.

As the UCS provides an Active Directory, you can connect all your windows clients. Thus you do not need to enroll the pGina.
As the UCS also provides simpleSAMLphp, you can also use SSO/SAML with the external applications - even with 2FA.

Comment: Thanks! I will check out Univention Corporate Server, it looks like it will suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Univention in Germany.

> First, does this sound like a good plan? Are there any other options
>   to consider?

In principle is fine. But I am not sure it's worth the effort for so small amount of users. Try UCS core edition (with [community support](https://help.univention.com/)).

- UCS has an LDAP-Kerberos bundle (read: enterprise directory) to which you can join OSX clients (Windows and Linux too)
- If you install it with Samba AD it will add that support for file shares, plus the functionality of an MS Active directory.
- There is an UCS APP called [SAML Identity Provider](http://wiki.univention.de/index.php?title=SAML_Identity_Provider) for Web Single Sign-on.
- As cornelius said, PrivacyIdea (also as App) will help you with Two-Factor Authentication

> Second, I'm a bit stuck on connecting third party web apps to
>   OpenLDAP. I know that most providers (including LastPass) use SAML for
>   SSO/federated access, but I don't know how to set that up. Does
>   OpenLDAP support SAML authentication? What if I want to enable MFA
>   (possibly including mobile authenticators and/or Yubikeys)?

Not directly. You can use something like SimpleSAMLphp in between.